# how to share data between apps using indexedDB in PWA projects

Tags: progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

We have two different Progressive Web App projects and they are using IndexedDB for manipulating data.

We need to share data between these apps but IndexedDB seems to allocate separate storages in Browser for different apps.

I wonder how we can achieve this using PWA?

Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the storage model for the web platform in general (not specific to progressive web apps) assumes that [origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) are boundary points, and that two web apps from different origins can't read each other's storage.

If you have two different web apps and you would like to ensure that they have access to each other's storage, the easiest approach would be to host them both on the same origin under two different URL prefixes, like `https://example.com/app1/` and `https://example.com/app2/`.

If that approach doesn't work, then instead of relying on local storage like IndexedDB, you should consider using a remote backend storage solution. That would allow the same user across multiple web apps to authenticate and access the same remote storage.

Comment: At this time its the same thing as you mentioned but the two projects have different ports but indexedDB doesn't let those two apps use the same storage.Also using remote server for this scenario is not possible as this data is used in the login page before user logs in.

Comment: The definition of an `origin` includes the port (which would default to `80` for HTTP and `443` for HTTPS). So you do need to make sure that you use the same port on each if you want the web apps to share the same origin.

Comment: as both webapps use port 443, then can two websites : a1.xxx.com, a2.xxx.com use same indexeddb then or they still have not same origin ?

Comment: No, they would have different origins and can't share IndexedDB.